# Copying files from one folder to another & rename at destination folder using shell scripting

Tags: linux, ssh

Actually I want to copy files from "folder-a" to "folder-b" using shell scripting, e.g, "folder-a" contain four files i.e;
file1
file2
file3
file4
but, when it copying to destination the script ask user to rename each file & then the script copy it to "folder-b" with new name.

Comment: What platform and shell are you targeting?

Comment: Ubuntu shell version bash

Answer (score 1):

Write this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $1/*; do
    read -p "New name for $f:" g
    scp $f $2/$g
done
```

And then on the command line:

```
./my-script.sh folder-a folder-b
```

Comment: Thank you for your co-operation but it is copying only one file not all files from "folder-a". Kindly do the need full.